# Python - IndexError - The Program removes the name from the list

Tags: python, index-error

I have a list and I want to delete an optional name but below the line

```
if newArray[i]==a:
```

it says "IndexError: list index out of range"

```
newArray = ['John','Alex','Sophia','Rick']

a = str(raw_input('Type your name if you want to delete : '))
if a in newArray:
    for i in range(len(newArray)):
        if newArray[i]==a:
            del newArray[i] # I want to delete it
        else:
            print newArray[i]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Loop backwards instead `for i in range(len(newArray)-1,-1,-1)`

Answer (score 0):

As the loop progresses, once you've removed an item from `newArray` it is no longer possible to get to the end of the  for loop. If `len(newArray)` is now 3, you can't get the fourth element, so `newArray[3]` will raise the error.

A more Pythonic way to do it might be to use a list comprehension.

```
if a in newArray:
    newArray = [i for i in newArray if i != a]
```

It could be slower than the `.index()` method for long lists though (though I'm not about to profile it and see).

Comment: This says the cause but not the fix.

Comment: True, but the question states the problem and doesn't ask for a fix…

Comment: I've suggested a fix.

Comment: Thank you ! I asked about the bug but forgot how to fix it . Thank you for helping ^^

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate and delete element from list at same time.

better do like this:

```
>>> a = raw_input("enter name to delete: ")
enter name to delete: Alex
>>> a
'Alex'
>>> if a in newArray:
...     del newArray[newArray.index(a)]
... 
>>> newArray
['John', 'Sophia', 'Rick']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop for this:

```
>>> newArray = ['John','Alex','Sophia','Rick']
>>> a = 'Alex'
>>> newArray.index(a)
1
>>> del newArray[newArray.index(a)]
>>> newArray
['John', 'Sophia', 'Rick']
```

Comment: What if `a` exists multiple times in that list?

Comment: Thank you for helping ^^

Comment: @AhsanulHaque That wasn't the OP's question, but since `.index()` returns the index of the first item the code above would simply remove the first instance of the item from the list.

If you want to deal with unique names, have a look at [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset)

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way as well.

```
newArray = ['John','Alex','Sophia','Rick']

a = str(raw_input('Type your name if you want to delete : '))

for name in newArray:
   if name == a:
      newArray.remove(name)

print newArray
```